# How does one get the original environment (variables) of a Python process?

Tags: python

What I want is to get the original/unmodified environment with which the Python process was called.

This is not what `os.environ` contains, as [PEP 538](https://peps.python.org/pep-0538/) makes Python mess around with that and set `LC_CTYPE` in some cases when it hadn't been set in the true environment of the process.

E.g. consider:

```
$ env -i python3
Python 3.10.4 (main, May 14 2022, 05:40:22) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os                      
>>> os.environb                                                
environ({b'LC_CTYPE': b'C.UTF-8'})
>>>
```

whereas the true environment of that process would have been empty (as per `env -i`) and as one can see e.g. in the process’:

```
$ hd /proc/100146/environ 
$
```

Another solution would be if one could find out whether PEP 538's locale coercing took place or not, i.e. whether `LC_CTYPE` was just added by Python, or actually part of the environment.

Thanks.

PS: I should add, that I'd like to get the true environment in a "pythonic" way... of course I could (at least on Linux) just read `/proc/$PID/environ`.

Comment: maybe spawn a subprocess to call `env`, and then process the output? actually not sure what you can try otherwise tbh.

Comment: That LC_CTYPE setting *is* set in the "true environment". Saying otherwise is like saying that the "true value" of `x` after `x = 1; x = 2` is `1`.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Well that might be more portable than using proc, but with the disadvantage that it doesn't really work when variable names contain newlines, e.g. consider `env -i $'++=\nFOO=4' env`   ... `env` even handles environment variables which are not valid (shell) variable names, but the newline makes it impossible to determine whether a var is set or not. Of course there is `-0` option in GNU's `env`), but than I'm back to non-portable.

Comment: (Would you prefer to turn off the locale coercion? You can do that by starting your Python process with the `PYTHONCOERCECLOCALE` environment variable set to `0`.)

Comment: @user2357112 No it's not... if one uses `env -i` ... then the environment is empty. You can also see this in proc`s `environ` file for the Python process. The use case is a program that serves as a wrapper.

I don't want to turn locale coercion off, I want to know what the exact original environment was. If I set `PYTHONCOERCECLOCALE=0` (which requires another warapper) then I wouldn't know whether that was set originally, or just by my extra wrapper.

Comment: @calestyo: `proc/<pid>/environ` doesn't show a process's actual environment variables. It shows whatever environment variables a process was initialized with, but it doesn't reflect changes dynamically.

Comment: @rv.kvetch btw: using `env` wouldn't work anyway... cause when it's called from within Python, it already uses the modified environment.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, but that's the question :-) ... I want the *original* environment i.e. that what the process gets when called via (C) `exec()` family of functions.

Comment: I'm not sure your goal is actually achievable in any portable way - I don't think POSIX requires the OS to preserve this information anywhere, and I don't think Python makes any attempt to preserve this information either. (I'm pretty sure `/proc/<pid>/environ` isn't POSIX.)

Comment: Sure, `/proc/` ain't POSIX. And no, I don't think there's any requirement for the OS to keep that. But e.g. C wouldn't just modify it. Others of course may do like Python. E.g. shells generally add (or at least set them as exported vars) at least `PWD`... and possibly more.

Comment: You could launch a process via one of the C `exec()` functions, take a snapshot of the environment, then have it start your Python code.

Comment: @constantstranger I guess that could work... but (no offence meant) it would also be quite ugly. I'd need to somehow pass that information to the Python process. Since that should serve as a fully transparent wrapper around some other program, I couldn't use env vars, nor command line arguments, nor standard streams. Even fd's in principle not.

Comment: @calestyo: You could easily encode your real environment variables in one or more fake ones (including the original values, if any, of those fake ones).

Comment: @DavisHerring Guess that's what constantstranger had in mind. And yes, in principle,... but then I'm at writing a wrapper for a wrapper (seems ugly and since the wrapper couldn't be Python, I could just do all with C in the 1st place).
Would however likely work in practise... though one in theory one could run into ´ARG_MAX` limits, because any encoding would need more space than without.